# xeditable defaultViewDate option for datepicker doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, x-editable

Any help would be appreciated I tried the below code for x-editable version 1.5.0 the other options like: 'weekStart' works but options like 'setDate', 'defaultViewDate' doesn't work is something wrong with my code?
My Code:

```
<a href="#" id="dob" data-type="date" data-pk="1" data-title="Select date">15/05/1984</a>

<script type="text/javascript>
$('#dob').editable({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  viewformat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  datepicker: {
    weekStart: 1,
    defaultViewDate: {
      year: 2012,
      month: 11,
      day: 11
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: post some more code and ask a clear question

Comment: please check now.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?"

Comment: The Datepicker shows the current date(Today) not the defaultviewdate which is provided.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/akash_shah117/z0yqgL9k/2/

Comment: make sure you're asking about bootstrap-datepicker because at this moment you evoke something else than datepicker self ```$('#dob').editable({```.   More over bootstrap-datepicker works with input[type='text'] not <a> link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `data-value` attribute in your HTML to set default date value

```
<a href="#" id="dob" data-type="date" data-value="2012-11-11" data-pk="1" data-title="Select date"></a>
```

this is a workaround [check updated jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/z0yqgL9k/4/).

If you want to open datepicker with default date, when `data-value` is empty. you can use `defaultValue` option of editable.

```
$('#dob').editable({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    viewformat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    url: '/post',
    defaultValue: "11/11/2012"
})
```

check example here http://jsfiddle.net/z0yqgL9k/6/

Comment: data-value will select the value but i don't want that i want even if the data-value is empty the datepicker to open with default date.

Comment: @AkashShah check edited answer , i guess this is what you want.

Comment: I already got this working with the same option yesterday so i will accept it.Its an alternative.