# Editing Value of X-Editable Field When EditableForm Opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker, x-editable

I've currently got a list of editable datepicker fields like this:

```
<a href="#" class="visit-date editable editable-click" id="visit-date531-396-1">05/01/2018*</a><br>
<a href="#" class="visit-date editable editable-click" id="visit-date531-397-1">05/03/2018*</a><br>
<a href="#" class="visit-date editable editable-click" id="visit-date531-377-1">05/10/2018*</a>
```

Now, when I click on these fields, the datepicker field itself is blank. That's because the value of each element with the `*` cannot be parsed into a date and therefore it just shows empty in the field.

How can I sanitize this value BEFORE editing the field so that the date is shown in the editable form text box?

I've tried the below using the `value` option of the editable field:

```
value:function(input) {
    return $(this).text().replace(/\*/g, '');
},
```

However, that does not work and in fact causes the editableform to fail completely (no editableform loads).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's unrelated to what I'm trying to do exactly, however, I found this question here: [xeditable defaultViewDate option for datepicker doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463722/xeditable-defaultviewdate-option-for-datepicker-doesnt-work#40464674)

That led me to the `data-value` attribute which allows the explicit value of that editable to be set in the HTML. After finding that answer, I noticed this attribute mentioned in the X-Editable documentation, but it's mentioned pretty inexplicitly, so it's extremely easy to miss.

I changed my html so that it became the following and this is working for me.

```
<a href="#" class="visit-date editable editable-click" id="visit-date531-396-1" data-value="05/01/2018">05/01/2018*</a><br>
<a href="#" class="visit-date editable editable-click" id="visit-date531-397-1" data-value="05/03/2018">05/03/2018*</a><br>
<a href="#" class="visit-date editable editable-click" id="visit-date531-377-1" data-value="05/10/2018">05/10/2018*</a>
```